# Using ACR (adaptive clock recovery) across pseudowire

Tags: cisco-ios, pseudowire

I am using back to back Cisco 2941s (mwr2941-adviprank9-mz.151-3.MRA3) in the lab to attempt to establish a pseudowire circuit for T1 delivery. I am trying to establish timing by using adaptive clock recovery (ACR) in master/slave mode with the master being clocked with a BITS source. [This is listed as supported in the 2941 documentation](https://content.cisco.com/chapter.sjs?uri=%2Fsearchable%2Fchapter%2Fwww.cisco.com%2Fcontent%2Fen%2Fus%2Ftd%2Fdocs%2Fwireless%2Fmwr_2941_dc%2Fsoftware_config%2Fguide%2F2941_Config%2FRANOcfg.html.xml&platform=Cisco%20MWR%202900%20Series%20Mobile%20Wireless%20Routers&release=15.0%281%29MR)

the pseudowire is established as satop with udp encapsulation like so (single config shown for brevity):

```
controller T1 0/3
 clock source internal
 linecode b8zs
 cablelength long 0db
 cem-group 0 unframed

interface CEM0/3
 no ip address
 cem 0
  xconnect 192.168.1.33 199 pw-class pw-udp
   udp port local 49152 remote 49152
   
pseudowire-class pw-udp
 encapsulation udp
ip local interface Vlan199
 ip tos value 100
 ip ttl 100
 
interface Vlan199
 description "PWE network"
 ip address 192.168.1.34 255.255.255.0
 no ptp enable
end
```

Everything pertaining to the xconnect and cem is working as expected:

```
2941-pwLab-1#sh pw-udp vc
Local intf        Local circuit              VC ID      Status
----------------- -------------------------- ---------- ---------------
CE0/3:0           SATOP T1                   199        established
  LAddr: 192.168.1.34   LPort: 49152
  RAddr: 192.168.1.33   RPort: 49152


2941-pwLab-1#sh xconnect all
Legend:    XC ST=Xconnect State  S1=Segment1 State  S2=Segment2 State
  UP=Up       DN=Down            AD=Admin Down      IA=Inactive
  SB=Standby  HS=Hot Standby     RV=Recovering      NH=No Hardware

XC ST  Segment 1                         S1 Segment 2                         S2
------+---------------------------------+--+---------------------------------+--
UP     ac   CE0/3:0(SATOP T1)            UP udp  192.168.1.33:199            UP

2941-pwLab-1#sh cem circuit
CEM Int.       ID   Ctrlr     Admin     Circuit         AC
--------------------------------------------------------------
CEM0/3         0    UP        UP        Active           UP
```

However with the following network-clock config, i am unable to get timing over the pseudowire:

LAB 1 with wired BITS:

```
controller BITS
  applique T1
  framing esf
  
network-clock-select hold-timeout infinite
network-clock-select mode nonrevert
network-clock-select 1 BITS
```

LAB 2 with ACR

```
recovered-clock recovered adaptive cem 0 3 0

network-clock-select hold-timeout 900
network-clock-select mode nonrevert
network-clock-select 1 PACKET-TIMING
```

I am trying to determine why my lab 2 device remains in free-run, and changing encapsulation to MPLS, and changing to CESoPSN has not had any effect.

Any advice on decoding SAToP in wireshark would be appreciated as well, [it is shown to be supported](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/p/pwsatopcw.html) but I am unable to determine if timing is even being inserted into any packets between the two devices.